# Ошибка сборки APK Unity

Tags: android, unity3d, разработка-игр, unity3d-editor

При сборке с keystore выходит ошибка в консоли и APK не сохраняется
Использую Unity 2017

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: Ошибка 2]

Comment: Ошибку вставьте текстом, чтоб люди с похожей проблемой могли этот вопрос найти.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Эта проблема была в Android SDK Build Tools v.26.0.0. Они там [потеряли apksigner](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62696222). Обновите sdk.

P.S. саму ошибку вставлять лучше текстом.